# Plotting recursive function using pgfplots \addplot

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to plot a recursive function using pgfplots `\addplot` command?

I tried like this;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fac}{1}{
  \pgfmathparse{(#1<=1)+
                (#1>1)*#1*fac(#1-1)
  }
}

\begin{document}
fac(5) is \pgfmathparse{fac(5)}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

But the result seems to be an infinite recursion, as the entire function is being evaluated.

Comment: if you define them properly yes.

Comment: @percusse: I've tried just getting a simple recursive fibonacci function to plot, but it like I'm triggering an infinite recursion whatever I do. Could you provide an example, say with the fibonacci function?

Comment: It might be better if you add what you've tried so far in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so it's easier to work out where you're going wrong and less effort to provide you with a working example.

Comment: @DaiBowen: Alike this?

Comment: @Skeen The recursive function does not terminate. But even with a proper termination (`ifthenelse`, ...), there is the problem that the arguments are evaluated first. Thus there is an infinite recursion *before* the stop condition is evaluated. Thus, the recursive function needs to be defined at lower level. Unhappily, there are several different lower levels (e.g. standard, `fpu`, `fixed point arithmetic`, ...). Package `pgfplots` uses the numbers in the format of library `fpu`.

Comment: @Skeen There is a [closed form for Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression), so no need for recursion.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Fibonacci was just the simple example case, not the function I actually want to plot.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I'm afraid I'm in no way familiar with the internal workings of `pgfplots` or how to define my function with `fpu`. Do you know of a 'Getting Started' guide or similar for this?

Comment: @Skeen It is much easier to calculate the values externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following Heiko Oberdiek's suggestion of calculating the values externally (in this case by using luacode, within LuaLatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
\begin{luacode*}
function fib(n)
    local function inner(m)
        if m < 2 then
            return m
        end
        return inner(m-1) + inner(m-2)
    end
    return inner(n)
end

local points = "";
for i=0,15,1 do
    points = points .. " (" .. i .. "," .. fib(i) .. ")";
end

tex.print("\\addplot [mark=none] coordinates { " .. points .. "};");
\end{luacode*}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields this:

[image: Result]