# How do you plot a recursive sequence in pgfplots/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, recursion

I'm trying to plot a recursive sequence namely x(1)=1, x(n+1)=1/2[x(n)+2/x(n)]. I've tried messing around with the `\tikzmath` library but so far I'm not really successfull. My main issue is properly defining the function, not sure how or even what tool to use to do so. Plotting it is the easy part though. 
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What about [recursive functions in pgfplots using 'declare function'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447190/73317)?

Comment: There is also [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340256/73317) using LuaTeX (the recursion is coded in Lua).

Comment: @frougon That should work thanks, I'll give it a go when I have time.